# About renewcommand

Tags: macros

I'm new to LaTeX and I was wondering how to write a command that gives me `\left\{A,B\right\}`. I want to renew this command like `\poisson`, for example.

If someone could help me, I will be very grateful.

Sorry if the question is basic.

Thanks.

Comment: `\newcommand{\poisson}{\left\{A,B\right\}}` in preamble, and then should be used in math mode. If you want to make `A,B` variables, you can. So would use `\newcommand{\poisson}[2]{\left\{#1,#2\right\}}` as `\poisson{X}{Y}`.

Comment: Package `physics`  already has `\pb{A}{B}`.

Comment: Sometimes defining a simple command can do the job, sometimes using one of the thousands of packages adding extra functionality to basic LaTeX can do the job. Depends.